# Wordpress create column in table when plugin activated

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I tried to find answer for my very noob question but did find it exactly for my question( 
I'm using maybe_add_column() function, but it looks not very good when call it each time when plugin is used, so how i can make sure that this function is completed once plugin is activated when i'm want to not add it to the main plugin code file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your plugin file.

```
function create_team_db() {
 global $wpdb;
 $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

 //* Create the teams table
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'all_teams';
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
 team_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 team_name TEXT NOT NULL,
 team_city TEXT NOT NULL,
 team_state TEXT NOT NULL,
 team_stadium TEXT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (team_id)
 ) $charset_collate;";
 dbDelta( $sql );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_team_db' );
```